# Is the mystic artisan still available in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

The mystic artisan has been touted as the third artisan to join us in our fight against the darkness.

Is the mystic still available in the released game and if so when can they be unlocked?

Comment: Travis Day confirmed that they will put the Mystic back in game soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No** They remove it for good.

> The design team is currently looking at systems and cleaning them up,
>   removing any superfluous system objectives and those that are beyond
>   fixing. Thus, we're removing the Mystic artisan. As we look at the big
>   picture, the Mystic simply wasn’t adding anything to our customization
>   system. Enhancement was really just the socket and gem system with a
>   different name, and it would prolong the release of the game even
>   further to go back to the drawing board and differentiate it, so we’ll
>   revisit the Mystic and enhancements at a later time. Removing her from
>   the game took some time, but it’s nowhere near the efforts that would
>   be required to flesh out a better customization system. We hope she’ll
>   be able to join your caravan in the future, but for now we’re going to
>   focus on the extensive customization options the game already offers.

Sources: [Diablo Forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3932854594), [Diablo web site](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4325959/Systems_Changes-1_19_2012#blog)

As you can see in the quest [**Empty spots in the last 2 cities**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68395/empty-spots-in-the-last-2-cities) [the answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68396/12936) states.

> Presumably, these spaces were intended for the artisan that would have
>   been the Mystic, whose function varied over time, but originally
>   included identification, crafting spellcaster items, and creating
>   scrolls and charms. As these things were removed or made simpler, her
>   purpose was obviated and so she was removed.

As @Raven said in [his comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68395/empty-spots-in-the-last-2-cities#comment95504_68396)

> Fun Fact: This artisan is still in the game as Karyna, the woman you
>   rescue from the Spider Dungeon.