# Empty spots in the last 2 cities

Tags: diablo-iii

I just remarked that there is an empty spot in the last 2 cities of the game. I have ended the game on normal, and no crafters took that space. Is it used? or is it just there because something got pulled from the game last minute?

[image: Screenshot of the empty area in the Hidden Camp in Caldeum that is next to Leah's belongings and across the path from the Blacksmith (behind where Squirt is now, although this is an older screenshot)]
[image: Screenshot of the empty area in Bastion's Keep between the entrance to the Keep Depths and the doorway out to Arreat Gate and the Skycrown Battlements]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presumably, these spaces were intended for the artisan that would have been the Mystic, whose function varied over time, but originally included identification, crafting spellcaster items, and creating scrolls and charms. As these things were removed or made simpler, her purpose was obviated and so she was removed. To quote Blizzard on the matter:

> The design team is currently looking at systems and cleaning them up,
>   removing any superfluous system objectives and those that are beyond
>   fixing. Thus, we're removing the Mystic artisan. As we look at the big
>   picture, the Mystic simply wasn’t adding anything to our customization
>   system. Enhancement was really just the socket and gem system with a
>   different name, and it would prolong the release of the game even
>   further to go back to the drawing board and differentiate it, so we’ll
>   revisit the Mystic and enhancements at a later time. Removing her from
>   the game took some time, but it’s nowhere near the efforts that would
>   be required to flesh out a better customization system. We hope she’ll
>   be able to join your caravan in the future, but for now we’re going to
>   focus on the extensive customization options the game already offers.

Comment: Fun Fact: This artisan is still in the game as Karyna, the woman you rescue from the Spider Dungeon.

Comment: I was wondering what her purpose was. Interesting!

Comment: It definitely makes the quest to retrieve her staff make a little more sense.